# Help text for editing tag-wiki excerpts gives bad advice

Tags: feature-request, edits, wording, tag-wiki-excerpt

The [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) on tag-wiki excerpts says amongst others:

> **Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag,** unless it is highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does *not* need to explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate explanation of email to anyone.

Also, a possible reason for rejecting tag-wiki edits is:

> Simply defining what a [tag] *is* rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name *itself* is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe **why** and **when** a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.

However, when you try to edit a tag wiki, there is a help text on the right-hand side which begins with:

> The tag wiki **excerpt** is a brief plain text introduction to the topic that the tag represents.

This is almost a direct contradiction to the above and at the very least bad advice. I therefore suggest to change this text to something more helpful like:

> The tag wiki **excerpt** is a brief plain text introduction to *why* and *when* a tag should be used. It should resolve ambiguities and avoid other common misuses of the tag.